# How to authenticate against an external custom database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, oauth

A company uses username/password to login into their application, which they authenticate against their own database.

We would like to use the same userid for authenticating against our rails app as well.

How should we enable this integration?
How should we pass the login credentials to the external systems.
What should be the preferred approach to resolve this issue.

Comment: There is no right approach - and any possible solution depends on what you are working with LDAP, Oauth, ActiveDirectory or something built out of straws and glue-code - if you can provide any more details then maybe the question is answerable.

Comment: The intention is to support many customers each having their own auth scheme (say CustomerA supporting OAuth, CustomerB using Microsoft AD, CustomerC using username/password from a table). How ca we build a solution which provides the flexibility to support any of the above options.